# Where to get iOS device hardware strings before the release of an upcoming iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

The hardware string of an iOS device could be obtained in codes through xCode API.

However, I am preparing an iOS app before the release of iPhone 12 as of August 2020. My app has a mapping table to map a hardware string like `iPhone12,8` to `iPhone SE (gen 2)`, and I would like to add such mapping for iPhone 12.

Even though I know the hardware spec of iPhone 12 through https://www.gadgetsnow.com/mobile-phones/Apple-iPhone-12, I don't see Apple had published the hardware string of iPhone 12. Websites like https://iosref.com/hardware-strings list hardware strings of iOS devices but only current models.

Question 1: Where to get hardware string of an upcoming iPhone ASAP?

Question 2: Is there a table telling all hardware strings of all upcoming iPhone and iPad in next 5 years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware strings ore only included inside the os, so you should wait for the release of the IPSW in order to get it.

#### Answer 1:

There are some resources out there where contributors are tracking the version list and update it continuously like [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices) or [this gist file](https://gist.github.com/adamawolf/3048717) that you can use ASAP.

#### Answer 2:

No! There is nowhere to tell you the next 5 years plan of the company's strategy of release. (even nowhere for the next year )

Comment: Among many similar Websites that provides such mapping, IPSW seems to be the most promptly updated, since they provide the links to IPSW. Strange enough, while many Website get the spec before the release, none provide hardware string before the release.